# Getting Success/Failure Response from PowerShell Enable/Disable User script

Tags: powershell

how to Get Success/Failure Response from PowerShell Enable/Disable User  using following scripts.I need to update the status of the user.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter mail -eq $mail | Disable-ADAccount
Get-ADUser -Filter 'mail -eq "ed@gmail.com"' | Enable-ADAccount
```

Please advice me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the `-passthru` parameter to the `enable-Adaccount` and that will pass the user object along with all its properties. You then want to select the `enabled` user property.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'mail -eq "ed@gmail.com"' | 
    Enable-ADAccount -PassThru | Select-Object Enabled
```

Comment: Same goes for `Disable-ADAccount -PassThru`

Comment: Working Thanks a Lot